# Extract substring from a string using Python regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string

I am working with data frames. One of my column look like this

```
                   X
4028    Toolx-2022-01-18_15-26-09.blf.26
4029    Temperaturelow-2022-01-18_15-26-09.blf.27
4031    Temperaturehigh2022-01-18_15-26-09.blf.28
4032    low2022-01-18_15-26-09.blf.29
4032    high2022-01-18_15-26-09.blf.30
Name: X, dtype: object
```

I want my output like this

```
                  X
4028    2022-01-18 15-26-09 26
4029    2022-01-18 15-26-09 27
4030    2022-01-18 15-26-09 28
4031    2022-01-18 15-26-09 29
4032    2022-01-18 15-26-09 30
Name: X, dtype: object
```

Can anyone please help me how to do this in Python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str.extract` here:

```py
df["X"] = df["X"].str.extract(r'(\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})_(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}).*\.(\d+)', r'\1 \2 \3')
```

Here is a regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/APiBu1/1).

Comment: Thanks for taking time and answering. I tried the above code and I got this error 'unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int' '

Comment: My answer will only work if the `X` column is string.  I make this assumption in my answer.

Comment: My X column  dtype is object only

Comment: Use a string column so that you may take advantage of the Pandas `str` functions.

Comment: Hmm, I tried that, still facing the same error

Comment: If `X` is string, you won't face the error.  If you can't use a string column, then my answer won't work.

Comment: Hmm , I converted to string and still facing the same error. Strange !.

Comment: Try printing `df["X"].str.extract(...)` by itself.  Does that cause an error?

Comment: Yes , still an error